# QT creating huge grid with clickable items

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qgraphicsscene

I want to make a huge grid of buttons (500-1000 cells) with 16x16 size and I'm unsure what is the best way to do it.
I tried to do it with QTableView, but code below didn't make cells small enough (it works for with bigger sizes)

```
QHeaderView * vertHeader = ui->view->verticalHeader();
vertHeader->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Fixed);
vertHeader->setDefaultSectionSize(16);
vertHeader->setVisible(false);
QHeaderView * horHeader = ui->view->horizontalHeader();
horHeader->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Fixed);
horHeader->setDefaultSectionSize(16);
horHeader->setVisible(false);
```

And here's how cells look compared to 30x30 rectangle:

[image: size of empty cells compared to 30x30 gray rectangle]

Is it possible to make cells smaller? And/or is it better to just use QGraphicsScene for that task?

I also thought about using QGridLayout, but won't performance with it be terrible?

Comment: Do you want the "buttons" specifically? Will something like one big clickable scene, where you just detect the coordinates and determine which "virtual button" they belong too work for you?

Comment: @DanM. I think it will work for me, but how much harder it is to implement it? Especially if I want button to look pressed while mouse button is pointing on it and also pressed

Comment: I would say try the naive approach (QGridLayout) first and see.

Comment: @crends Alexandre already pointed out the solutions. I'll just add that I did something similar in QML and there it was trivial. Not sure about pure QWidget based implementation, but I reckon it's no much harder, just more boilerplate-y. Especially if you do not try to emulate how native buttons look.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you want to do with these buttons. But with so many items to display, it could take a few seconds to create the components if you use a real button (e.g. QPushButton) for each cell and you want to show them all at once.

a) To have better performance, an option is to simply subclass QWidget and reimplement `void paintEvent(..)` to draw all cells exactly like you want with a QPainter and to use `void mousePressEvent(..)` to detect clicks, and then do the math yourself to map the coordinates of the click to a cell. Putting this widget into a QScrollArea would allow to scroll around if it's too big to display.

b) The QGraphicsView framework is nice to display thousands of items as well. The implementation would be more powerful than a) but also a bit more complex. It would make sense if you plan to develop this view much more in the future, have other items to display, etc.

c) For the QTableView solution, you can try to use a delegate to have a little more control about how the cells are displayed.